# Does the Posix "access" syscall take ACLs into consideration?

Tags: c, linux, posix, system-calls, acl

According to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/access), the POSIX syscall

```
int access(const char *pathname, int mode);
```

does the following

> access() checks whether the calling process can access the file
> pathname. If pathname is a symbolic link, it is dereferenced.

Does it also check [ACLs](https://linux.die.net/man/5/acl), or just the rights of owner/group/others ? 
(assuming the OS&FS supports ACLs, and that there are ACLs on the file)

Specifically, does it check ACLs on Linux (when ACLs are enabled in the kernel and FS) ?

Comment: It does whatever the operating system that implements `access()` does. Not every operating system even has ACLs. Or permissions, of any kind.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik: Actually, not every filesystem has ACLs, or has them enabled.In addition to if the OS supports them. Of course, I am assuming the OS supports them, otherwise the question makes no sense in the first place.

Comment: As you quote: "_access() checks whether the calling process can access the file pathname._" This means that if the user owning the process can access the file, then the process can access the file. The user can access the file if he/she is on the ACL for the file. So the same holds for the process.

Comment: The man page for [acl_extended_fd](https://linux.die.net/man/3/acl_extended_fd) mentions " The access(2) system call can be used to check whether a given type of access to a file object would be granted. ". This sounds like it takes all access control mechanisms into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `access` should consider ACL and any other mechanisms that may be in place. Otherwise, it'd make `access` pointless. For example, if `access` says OK for reading a file but then an attempt to read the fails because of ACL or something else, that'd make it useless.

POSIX's access doesn't mention ACLs directly. But there are notes to suggest that additional mechanisms that may be present should be considered.

From POSIX's [access](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/access.html):

> [..] Likewise, if a system provides any additional or alternate file
> access control mechanisms that are not user ID-based, they will still
> be taken into account.

and

> Additional values of amode other than the set defined in the
> description may be valid; for example, if a system has extended access
> controls.